# Timers Elapsed event only on selected weekdays

Tags: c#, system.timers.timer

I am using timers in a windows service, which is simple and can write some data into a file whenever the event is elapsed. In this application I am trying to implement 3 types of cases:

1. event will be fired at same time(given StartTime) everyday.
2. Event which will be fired in some specific WeekDays say I want to do it only  on Monday, Tuesday and Saturday starting from a given StartTime.
3. Event which will be fired in some specific Months and in those months Specific WeekDays say I want to do it only on July and Sept but on restricted days Monday, Tuesday and Saturday starting from a given StartTime.

Till now what I implemented is for Case 1 and I am not sure about how to do the same for Case 2 and Case 3. (The logic I am thinking is weird). If I got some help in solving Case 2 will help in implementing Case 3 also. Any other Suggestions are most welcome.

Here is my Code:

```
   private static Timer aTimer;
        public static void Main()
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
             aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program... ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            String path = @"E:\sample1.txt";
            StreamWriter osw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
          Console.WriteLine("Enter the  case (1 or 2 or 3)");
                var ch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
                   switch (ch)
                {
                    default:  break;
                    case 1:aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEventCase1;
                        aTimer.Enabled = false; 
                        break;
                    case 2: aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                           aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEventCase2;
                        aTimer.Enabled = false; 
                        break;
                    case 3: aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                          aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEventCase3;
                        aTimer.Enabled = false; 
                        break;
                }

            osw.Close();
            osw = null;
           }
// Elapsed Event for Case 1
      private void OnTimedEventCase1(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
                Console.WriteLine("Daily Job");
                Console.WriteLine("DateTime: " + DateTime.Now);
                Timer theTimer = (System.Timers.Timer)source;
                theTimer.Interval = 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60; // will do it daily i.e, 24 hours
                theTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
// Elapsed Event for Case 2
     private void OnTimedEventCase2(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
          //  throw new NotImplementedException();
            string[] days = new string[]{"Monday", "Tuesday" ,"Saturday"};
            Console.WriteLine("WeekDays Job");
            Console.WriteLine("DateTime: " + DateTime.Now);
            Timer theTimer = (System.Timers.Timer)source;
            //theTimer.Interval = I don't know how to fire event here according weekdays  
            //theTimer.Enabled = true;

        }
// Elapsed Event for Case 3
      private void OnTimedEventCase3(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
          //  throw new NotImplementedException();
            string[] days = new string[]{"Monday", "Tuesday" ,"Saturday"};
            string[] months= new string[]{"July", "September"};
            Console.WriteLine("Monthly job");
            Console.WriteLine("DateTime: " + DateTime.Now);
            Timer theTimer = (System.Timers.Timer)source;
            //theTimer.Interval = I don't know how to fire event here according months and then weekdays
            //theTimer.Enabled = true;

        }
```

Though I can easily implement the elapsed event for hours and even for 1days which is constant amount of time I need to pass through timeInterval attribute but Here what I am not getting how to fire Elapsed event for Selected Weekdays and Selected Months.

Comment: `var arr = new List<string> { "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday" };
                if (arr.Contains(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
                {
                    _timer.Elapsed += _timer_elaspsed;
                }`

Comment: something like this?

Comment: thanks Amit That answer will solve it I guess.

Comment: just let us informed, what happens.

Comment: Yeah I am working on that

Comment: So What I found is that we can call elapsed event only one time if I do your way. So Question here is once we get "StartTime" which is associated to some Job say Job1, but your code fails because StartTime does not match the other day means, Job1 is firing Elapsed once. Here in time Elapsed I need to set some value, so that it will reoccur the next day. `Timer theTimer = (System.Timers.Timer)source;
                theTimer.Interval = 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60; // will do it daily i.e, 24 hours
                theTimer.Enabled = true;`  Like in this case it will work but rest Case 2 and 3 will fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80011/discussion-between-ashishraaj-and-amit-kumar-ghosh).

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") for this. It would be much simpler.

Here's the hardest part:

```
IObservable<DateTimeOffset> daily =
    Observable
        .Create<long>(o =>
        {
            var startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(15, 30, 0));
            if (startTime < DateTimeOffset.Now)
            {
                startTime = startTime.AddDays(1.0);
            }
            return Observable.Timer(startTime, TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0)).Subscribe(o);
        })
        .Select(n => DateTimeOffset.Now);
```

This code sets up an observable that will fire first at the time specified in the `new TimeSpan(15, 30, 0)` and then every day as specified in the `TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0)`. The `.Select(n => DateTimeOffset.Now)` means that the sequence will return the actual `DateTimeOffset` that it fired.

Now you just have to apply filters to get the other two observables you need:

```
IObservable<DateTimeOffset> weekday =
    from n in daily
    where new []
    {
        DayOfWeek.Monday,
        DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
        DayOfWeek.Saturday,
    }.Contains(n.DayOfWeek)
    select n;

IObservable<DateTimeOffset> monthWeekday =
    from n in weekday
    where new [] { 7, 9, }.Contains(n.Month)
    select n;
```

They are basically LINQ queries that filter out the events from `daily` that you don't want to fire.

Then you just need to add the code that actually consumes the events:

```
IDisposable dailySubscription =
    daily
        .Subscribe(n =>
        {
            /* daily work goes here */
        });

IDisposable weekdaySubscription =
    weekday
        .Subscribe(n =>
        {
            /* weekday work goes here */
        });

IDisposable monthWeekdaySubscription =
    monthWeekday
        .Subscribe(n =>
        {
            /* month/weekday work goes here */
        });
```

All you need to do to shut down each subscription is to call `.Dispose()` on them.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but here is the thing if start working on something new than It will take a lot of time as I will be needing to read the documentation of  "Rx-Main" and I probably don't wanna do that. Because I do have a logic to fit with that condition only as I just need to calculate some things and I can get the solution but that is not optimal I think thus I am waiting for correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the largest interval that will give you the best accuracy for your demands (you wrote you want it on a specific time of day, so an hour might be too big but 15 minutes would probably be OK), and inside the `Timer_Elapsed` event handler just check the conditions using `DateTime.Now`.

If the value of `DateTime.Now` fits case 1, call a method that will execute case 1.
If it fits case 2, call a method that will execute case 2,
and if it fits case 3, well, you get the picture, right?